# Why each time I create an issue in Jira, I triggers the Resolution input?

Tags: jira

Why each time when I create an issue in Jira, I triggers the Resolution input?

[image]

[image]

In `Column Management`, it is only when the status is `Done` that required `Resolution` input.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is because the resolution field is added to the creation screen, and on your Jira project the field has been set to be required.

To avoid this from happening make sure you have a different screen for creation and closing an issue, or just to remove field from the creation screen if you already have a separate screens

Jeff

Comment: How do I go to the creation screen?